# How to show pdf in webview in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, webview

How to show pdf in webview in flutter.

I have already uploaded pdf fle to fireabse database and storage.
.

Now I want to download and open te pdf  in retrieving page or homescreen

I have recieved the downloadURL of the pdf uploaded too

```
Container(
    child: PDfFile1 != null && WCardPDFURL == null ? PDF.file(
      PDfFile1,
      height: 600,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
    ) : PDfFile1 == null && WCardPDFURL == null?
    FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          _getLocalImage4();
        },   child: Icon(Icons.picture_as_pdf,size: 80,color:Colors.red,) ) :

    //Image.file(PDfFile1, width: 200, height: 100,),
    Image.file(
      PDfFile1,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      height: 250,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Can you please add your pdf URL from firebase so ill use this URL and answer this question?

Comment: Below is my pdf url                      
           https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/upload-image-7c0f4.appspot.com/o/DeviceDocs%2FDeviceDocs2021-01-08%2011%3A07%3A55.395840.pdf?alt=media&token=4bb083fd-4100-4f35-a287-4ac9997a9c0b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PDF file is in firebase storage you can create a url for your PDF with firebase storage. Then open this URL in a Web_view with `webview_flutter` plugin.

Comment: Please check my code edited above. But How to  reterieve the downloaded url and open  pdf using webview in retrieving page or home page?

Comment: Windsor_Elliot and Shubham I am eagerly waiting for the solution.

Comment: what will happen if the url is not in firebase storage?